# Multi-processing and file operations?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multiprocessing

In windows-based OS, assuming there are several different processes that may read and/or write a file freqently by using `fopen/fopen_s/fwrite` etc, in such case, do I need to consider data-races, or the OS can handle this automatically to ensure the file can only be opened/updated by a single process here at any given time whilst the rest fopen attemp will fail? And what about linux-based OS on this matter?

Comment: btw i recommend using OS api rather than standard c or c++ libraries in such case because standard c and c++ (not including c++11) are multi-processing or multi-threading agnostic.

Comment: @AliVeli That's not totally true: the `ios_base::app` and the `"a"` options are intended to be atomic where possible, so having multiple processes appending to the same file should work.  Anything more, however, and I'd agree---the system level calls are more appropriate.  (In particular, if you need locking, this is only possible with the system level calls.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows it depends on how you open the file.

see some possible values for `uStyle` parameter in case of [`OpenFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `dwShareMode` in case of [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Please note that `OpenFile` is kind of deprecated though so better use `CreateFile`.

Comment: If he's using iostream or the `FILE*` functions, he doesn't have any choice with regards to the `dwShareMode` argument.  From a QoI point of view, I would expect `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` (but my point of view may be influenced by my Unix background, where you don't have this argument, and the `open` works as if all of the `FILE_SHARE_...` options were set).

Comment: @James Kanze well true, I haven't taken into consideration that he/she wants to use iostream or cstdio functions. Then I commented on that under the original question.

Comment: @AliVeli Unless he's doing something simple (like always appending when writing), it's probably that the system level functions are more appropriate.  (But I thought that `OpenFile` was deprecated, and that one should always use `CreateFile` in new code.)

Comment: MSDN states the following regarding `OpenFile`: Note  This function has limited capabilities and is not recommended. For new application development, use the `CreateFile` function. So, indeed it is.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take care to not open the same file from multiple threads simultaneously - as it's entirely possible to open the file multiple times, and the OS may or may not do what you expect, depending on the mode you are opening the file in - e.g. if you create a new file it will definitely create two different files (one of which will disappear when it gets closed, because it was deleted by the other thread, great, eh?). The rules are pretty complex, and the worst part is that if you don't take extra care, you'll get "mixed up output to the same file" - so lines or even parts of lines get mixed from the two threads.

Even if the OS stops you from opening the same file twice, you will still have to deal with the consequences of "`FILE *` came back as `NULL`". What do you do then? Go back and try again, or fail, or?

I'm not sure I can make a good suggestion as to HOW to solve this problem, since you haven't described very well what you are doing to these files. There are a few different things that come to mind:

1. Keep a "register" of file-names, and a mutex for each file that has to be held to be able to open the file.
2. Use a single "file-thread" to read/write data on files, and just queue "I want to write this stuff to file aa.txt", and let the worker write as it goes along.
3. Use lower level file system calls, and use "exclusive" access to the files, with some sort of "backoff" behaviour in case of collision.

I'm sure there are dozens of other ways to solve the problem - it really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I want to do at the moment is the following: (1) process #1(not thread)  is responsible for the updating of the data (2) process #2 will ONLY read the data updating by process #1, however I need to ensure process #2 will only use completely updated data to avoid any mixed-up between old and new data, I think at least for windows, I dont need to do anything to avoid data race in this case?

Comment: "if you create a new file it will definitely create two different files" -- that's impossible with `fopen`, and the whole "deleted in other thread" scenario is impossible on Windows. Perhaps not the reason to downvote the entire answer because the matter is indeed complex and some of your solutions make sense, but...

Comment: in this case you have to implement a consumer-producer solution to notify the reading process that it can read data. You can use events of windows, for example. (CreateEvent, SetEvent, etc...)

Comment: @user0002128 That's true for a system level `WriteFile`; it's not necessarily true for `fwrite` or `ostream::write`.  It will be true if 1) you ensure that the stream has a buffer that is large enough for any single write, and you flush after each write.

Comment: @James Kanze: Yes, now I know its better and simplier to let OS API handling this.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: If you have two threads in Linux that creates a file each, you will end up with two files, one of which disappears. I admit I didn't spot the Windows tag.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.  If you're talking about different processes (and not
threads), the conventional data race conditions which apply to
threads don't apply.  However (and there is no difference
between Unix and Windows here):

- Any single `write`/`WriteFile` operation will be atomic. (I'm
  not 100% sure concerning Windows, but I can't imagine it
  otherwise.)  However, if you're using iostream or the older
  `FILE*` functions, you don't have direct control of when those
  operations take place.  Normally, they will only occur when the
  stream's buffer is full.  You'll want to ensure that the buffer
  is big enough, and explicitly flush after each output.  (If
  you're outputting lines of a reasonable length, say 80 
  characters at the most, it's a safe bet that the buffer will
  hold a complete line.  In this case, just use `std::endl` to
  terminate the lines in iostreams; for the C style functions,
  you'll have to call `setvbuf( stream, NULL, _IOLBF, 0 )` before
  the first output.
- Each open file in the process has its own idea of where to
  write in the file, and its own idea of where the end of file is.
  If you want all writes to go to the end of file, you'll need to
  open it with `std::ios_base::app` in C++, or "a" in C.  Just
  `std::ios_base::out`/`"w"` is not enough.  (Also, of course,
  with just `std::ios_base::out` or "w", the file will be
  truncated when it is opened.  Having several different processes
  truncating the file could result in loss of data.)
- When reading a file that other processes are writing to: when
  you reach end of file, the stream or `FILE` goes into an error
  state, and will not try to read further, even if other processes
  are appending data.  In C, `clearerr` should (I think) undo
  this, but it's not clear what happens next; in C++, clearing the
  error in the stream doesn't necessarily mean that further reads
  will not immediately encounter end of file either.  In both
  cases, the safest bet is to memorize where you were before each
  read, and if the read fails, close the file, then later reopen
  it, seek to where you were, and start reading from there.
- Random access, writing other than at the end of file, will
  also work, as long as all writes are atomic (see above); you
  should always get a consistent state.  If what you write depends
  on what you have read, however, and other processes are doing
  something similar, you'll need file locking, which isn't
  available at the iostream/`FILE*` level.

Comment: Does windows really guarantee that writes are atomic?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Hopefully.  I've never really been able to figure out what Windows guarantees, and what it doesn't.  But normally, system calls should be atomic.  (Although typically, even under Unix, there's a maximum size beyond which the write is no longer guaranteed to be atomic.)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I've checked it.  Windows guarantees atomicity if the size of the write is less than the size of a disk sector.  (Older Unix guaranteed it up to about 4K.  Curiously enough, I can't find any guarantee in Posix except when the file descriptor is a pipe.)